# Changing the server timezone to the local timezone

Tags: php, .htaccess, timezone

How can I change the timezone of server to the local time?

My server's timezone is `America/New_York` ,I want to change it to `Asia/Kolkata`, so when I run the following code :

```
echo date("h:i:s");
```

it will display the local time.

Is it possible by some changes in `.htaccess`?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible by `.htaccess`.

Add the following line to your `.htaccess` file

```
php_value date.timezone Asia/Kolkata
```

This will set **Asia/Kolkata** as default timezone on your server.

If this doesn't work, then try this:

```
SetEnv TZ Asia/Kolkata
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in htaccess using the following line:

```
SetEnv TZ Asia/Kolkata
```

Or the htaccess php.ini equivalent:

```
php_value date.timezone "Asia/Kolkata"
```

But you might be better served doing this in PHP by placing this directly in your php.ini file:

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata"
```

Or this in a common config file:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata')
```

Answer (score 0):

[date_default_timezone_set](http://mk:@MSITStore:C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CNuSphere%5CPhpED%5Chelp%5Cphp_manual_en.chm::/res/function.date-default-timezone-get.html)
(PHP 5 >= 5.1.0)

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date("h:i:s"); 
...
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/WOgtZ2)

---

If you prefer to set the default timezone on the `.htaccess`, try this:

```
SetEnv TZ Asia/Kolkata
```

---

If you want to change the **server default timezone**:

```
sudo mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime
```